# Changing specific elements on an HTML page without reloading

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a webpage displaying images of products in a certain color. There's a sidebar menu listing other color options, and when the user clicks one of those options (ex. "Blue"), I want to replace the currently-displayed images with images of the user-selected color -- without the page reloading.

I don't know Ajax or jQuery, only HTML/CSS/JS. So the way I set about doing this was creating some JavaScript functions that are called when the user clicks on a color link. See below:

Here's the HTML for the divs displaying the product images (basically the Dreamweaver eCommerce template with some ID attributes added in):

```
    <section class="mainContent">

    <div class="productRow"><!-- Each product row contains info of 3 elements -->
      <article class="productInfo" id="1">
          <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
          <p class="productContent">Mermaid</p>
      </article>

      <article class="productInfo" id="2">
          <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
          <p class="productContent">Impression</p>
      </article>

      <article class="productInfo" id="3">
          <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
          <p class="productContent">Summer Days</p>
      </article>
  </div>

  <div class="productRow">
    <article class="productInfo" id="4">
        <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
        <p class="productContent">Content holder</p>
    </article>

    <article class="productInfo" id="5">
        <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
        <p class="productContent">Content holder</p>
    </article>

    <article class="productInfo" id="6">
        <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
        <p class="productContent">Content holder</p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div class="productRow">
      <article class="productInfo" id="7">
          <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
          <p class="productContent">Content holder</p>
      </article>

      <article class="productInfo" id="8">
          <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
          <p class="productContent">Content holder</p>
      </article>

      <article class="productInfo" id="9">
          <div><img alt="sample" src="images/200x200.png"></div>
          <p class="productContent">Content holder</p>
      </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

The corresponding JavaScript:

```
function showBlue() {
    var imgs = ["blue101", "blue102", "blue103", "blue104", "blue105"]; // array to store file names
    for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(i).innerHTML += "<div><img alt='Product Image' src='" + blue[i] + ".jpg'></div><p class='productContent'>Blue</p>"; // note: all images are of type JPG
    }
}
```

Finally, a sample link from my sidebar menu. (I did want to use links for this, but  didn't work for me. If someone has a way to make that work too, that'd be great, but the main issue is just getting the image-replacing function to work).

```
<button onclick="showBlue()">Blue</button>
```

Currently, the images don't show up and the console says it can't read property innerHTML of null. I think that has to do with the fact that I'm calling document.getElementById() on an integer variable *i* when it's looking for a string, since the id attributes are all of type string. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `imgs` array does not look like any `id`s I see on your page. `var doc = document; function Q(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector); } function showBlue(){ for(var i=0,n=1,q=Q('img'),l=q.length; i<l; i++,n++){ q[i].src = 'images/blue10'+n+'.jpg'; } }`. Remember that HTML attributes can be easily set by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use `data-` attributes on the outermost clickable elements, which should probably be buttons for web accessibility's sake, but yea, you can select those by id or class etc

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.colorButton');
      buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          doSomethingWith(event.target.dataset.color);
        });
      });
```

You could also style those buttons to look like links, but generally links should actually be 'going' somewhere, even if it's within the same document. I think the trick is to use `href='#'` or `href=''` if you don't want it to actually go anywhere, but I don't recommend that, just use CSS styles that target `.colorButton` (you can add hover effects or 'active' effects like changing color) or use inline styles like `style='background: none;'` etc.

I recommend to mess around in the webpage devtools before hardcoding anything in your editor (styles and JS)

---

Also, I would not really recommend using innerHTML, which can be a source of XSS (cross site scripting) if you're not careful. It's kinda like 'eval' to render whatever is given to you from the server, though you're probably fine. The alternative is like, line by line construction using `document.createElement`, `element.setAttribute`, `element.appendChild`, etc

I would create a function that makes one of those image containers, and given a certain color creates the correct children.